# Adding NuGet AdDuplex AdControl to windows phone 8 project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, nuget-package

I tried to add the AdDuplex AdControl in Visual Studio 2012 for a Windows Phone 8 app by following this [Link](https://www.adduplex.com/ClientArea/Docs#wp8).

But it shows the error in the image.

[image]

How could i install this Adduplex pack into the project.

Answer (score 1):

In Your VS 2012 Tools => library package manager => CLick package manager console

Now Enter

PM>Install-Package AdDuplexWindows

Answer (score 0):

The issue (most likely) is that you are adding this to a project that used to be a Windows Phone 7.x project, right? In this case nuget gets confused and displays this error.

A fix is to remove all the nuget references from your project and re-add them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by updating NuGet first:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget

"Updating NuGet in Visual Studio"

After updating NuGet I was able to install AdDuplex.